# How to create a Telephone Directory using a CSV data base

Tags: csv, directory

I have created a excel file with Name,Title,Designation,Department,Faculty,Institute,TelNo,Email id columns

I want section wise telephone directory, i.e., We have 16 Faculties. So I want to create a Chapter/section title such as "Faculty of xyz" and under it Section or Subsections like "Department of abc" and below it the names of faculty members with their telephone numbers.

Is it possible to create such a Directory?

Comment: It should be possible. However, it will be easier to help you if you provide an example table in your question.

Comment: tabular* and tabularx both provide tables with a specific width.

Comment: If it is only a small table, you can use this interactive [table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/), which supports importing from CSV.

Answer (score 3):

The `csvsimple` package is for you. Given an archive in .csv format you can obtain a table (`tabular` or `longtable`) containing only the data required. In the example below I used the `filter equal` key to print only the rows that match a certain value in the "Department" column (which is the forth column, so `\csvcoliv`). I preferred to use a `longtable` environment as I expect some tables to span two pages (or more).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{test.csv}
  Name,Title,Designation,Department,Faculty,Institute,TelNo,EmailID
  Isaak Bacharach,Doctor,Foo,Mathematics,Science,Foo,234234123,foo@gmail.com
  Reinhold Baer,Professor,Foo,Chemics,Science,Foo,234234123,loo@gmail.com
  Christian Bär,Doctor,Loo,Physics,Science,Loo,234234123,foogmail.com
  Wolf Barth,Professor,Foo,Physics,Science,Foo,234234123,loo@gmail.com
  Friedrich L. Bauer,Professor,Loo,Chemics,Science,Loo,234234123,foogmail.com
  August Beer,Doctor,Foo,Sociology,Literature,Foo,234234123,loo@gmail.com
  Walter Benz,Professor,Loo,Physics,Science,Loo,234234123,foogmail.com
  Rudolf Berghammer,Professor,Foo,Sociology,Literature,Foo,234234123,loo@gmail.com
  Felix Bernstein,Professor,Loo,Physics,Science,Loo,234234123,foogmail.com
  Ludwig Berwald,Doctor,Foo,Philosophy,Literature,Foo,234234123,loo@gmail.com
  Karl Bobek,Professor,Loo,Sociology,Literature,Loo,234234123,foogmail.com
  Friedrich Böhm,Doctor,Foo,Philosophy,Literature,Foo,234234123,loo@gmail.com
  Oskar Bolza,Professor,Loo,Chemics,Science,Loo,234234123,foogmail.com
  Karl-Heinz Boseck,Professor,Foo,Chemics,Science,Foo,234234123,loo@gmail.com
  Hermann Bottenbruch,Doctor,Loo,Philosophy,Literature,Loo,234234123,foogmail.com
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\getphonelist}[1]{%
  \begin{longtable}[l]{lll}
    \bfseries Person & \bfseries Tel.~No. & \textbf{Email ID}
    \csvreader[head to column names,filter equal={\csvcoliv}{#1}]{test.csv}{}%
    {\\ \Name & \TelNo & \texttt{\EmailID}}
\end{longtable}}

\begin{document}
  
\csvautolongtable{test.csv}
  
\section*{Faculty of Science}
  \subsection*{Department of Mathematics}
    \getphonelist{Mathematics}
  
  \subsection*{Department of Physics}
    \getphonelist{Physics}
  
\section*{Faculty of Literature}
  \subsection*{Department of Philosophy}
    \getphonelist{Philosophy}
  
  \subsection*{Department of Sociology}
    \getphonelist{Sociology}
  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working after several tries! I will return back if I have any doubts.

Comment: The above example worked fine. My data has blanks so how to skip them. I have collected e-mail ids. But because of @ errors are coming and I am unable to include email id in the  output.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "skip them". Do you want to ignore all lines that do not have complete data (for example, phon num missing)? With regard to the email addresses, I updated the example, including those too.  The `@` character doesn't seem to cause errors.

Comment: This is the data : "Abhay Kumar Mishra ,Dr. ,Assoct. Professor,German Studies ,Arts,,,,9651713430,,End". Now wherever the field is blank it is shown by ",". In my output I am mixing two columns - OfficeLandNo and CUG Phone No; ResidenceLandNo and Mobile number separated by a "," In output If number column is blank then the "," should not come. I think it is possible with a boolean. Yes or No. If yes then how?